# Java Multithreading - State of an Idle thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

1. I'm new to Java Multithreading. Curious to know the state of idle thread incase of ThreadPoolExecutor. Is it in RUNNABLE/WAITING?
2. In case the idle threads are in RUNNABLE state, how are the new tasks attached to idle threads? AFAIK we assign a runnable/callable object to thread/pool. But my question is how does ThreadPoolExecutor assign queued runnable objects to idle thread??

Comment: well you can find an implementation here https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/

Comment: Thanks @AlbertoSinigaglia. This helped

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to find out:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ThreadExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        // force the threads to be started
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            executor.execute(() -> {
                try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            });
        }
        // don't terminate
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

Run it:

```
$ javac ThreadExample.java
$ java ThreadExample
```

In another console, having waited at least one second for the tasks to complete:

```
$ ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 3640 ttys000    0:00.25 -bash
 5792 ttys000    0:00.15 java ThreadExample
 5842 ttys001    0:00.05 -bash
$ jstack 5792
...
"pool-1-thread-1" #12 prio=5 os_prio=31 cpu=1.77ms elapsed=13.37s tid=0x00007fe99f833800 nid=0xa203 waiting on condition  [0x00007000094b2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.2/Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000061ff9e998> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.2/LockSupport.java:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@11.0.2/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(java.base@11.0.2/LinkedBlockingQueue.java:433)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(java.base@11.0.2/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.2/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.2/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.2/Thread.java:834)
...
```

All the pool threads are in that state.

Comment: As per ThreadExecutorService.java, all idle threads are in Runnable state. The code suggested above shows waiting because the current thread is sleeping.

The runState provides the main lifecycle control, taking on values:
  RUNNING
  SHUTDOWN
  STOP
  TIDYING
  TERMINATED

Comment: What's `ThreadExecutorService` and how does the state of the main thread affect other threads? Don't confuse a `runState` of the executor of `RUNNING` with the state of the threads.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Curious to know the state of idle thread in case of ThreadPoolExecutor. Is it in RUNNABLE/WAITING?

It will be WAITING.  It is waiting (in a `Queue.take()` call) for a new task to appear on the work queue.  In the current implementations this involves a mechanism similar to `wait` / `notify`.

Your second question is therefore moot.

However, it is worth noting the following:

1. No "idle" thread will ever be RUNNABLE.
2. In current generation HotSpot JVMs, the actual scheduling (deciding which threads get priority and assigning them a core to run on) is handled by the operating system.
3. In Loom JVMs (Loom is still an Incubator project), light-weight [virtual threads](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main#Main-VirtualThreads) ("fibres") are scheduled (to a native thread) by the JVM rather than the OS.